# How to find length of the longest field in each column from resultset

Tags: java, mysql

I know I can find the longest field in a column from specific table using by executing :

```
Statement s;
ResultSet r; 
r=s.executeQuery("SELECT MAX(LENGTH(field_to_query)) FROM table_to_query;");
```

But is there a way to get longest field in each column of obtained ResultSet after executing a query in Java:

**Example:**
I have executed:

```
r=s.executeQuery("select * from emlployee,department where d_id=dept_id and dept_name="Research");
```

now I want to get length of longest field in each column in r.

Thank you

Comment: Just use `max(length())` on each column.

Comment: May you please explain little more?

Comment: why negative vote? :(

Comment: I think it were reasonable question - and improved on the supplied answer. See @achabahe 's below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you go i have created i utility class that will give you an array of int that represents the max size of each column

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class MyDbUtility {
    private MyDbUtility(){}
    public static int[] maxColumns(final ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
        int columnNumber = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        int[] max = new int[columnNumber];
        int currentRow = resultSet.getRow();
        int fetchDirection = resultSet.getFetchDirection();
        if (fetchDirection == ResultSet.FETCH_FORWARD) {
            resultSet.beforeFirst();
        }else {
            resultSet.afterLast();
        }

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= columnNumber; i++) {
                if (resultSet.getString(i).length() > max[i-1]) {
                    max[i-1] = resultSet.getString(i).length();
                }
            }
        }
        resultSet.absolute(currentRow);
        return max;
    }
}
```

**usage**

```
    int[] max=MyDbUtility.maxColumns(reslut);
```

Comment: you are welcome i forgot System.out.println in the while loop you can delete it

Comment: i htink you would better make the max have an upper boundary so if an entery is larger than tht boundary it should be displayed in two lines or more

Comment: i have deleted that line and added a private constructor

Answer (score 2):

use the same query and find the max of every column , you are so close

```
    SELECT MAX(LENGTH(field_to_query1))as f1 , MAX(LENGTH(field_to_query2))as f2 FROM table_to_query;
```

Comment: You might try to expand on this answer. I.e. mention to build up a dynamic sql containing all of the "field_to_query_<N>" into a single sql statement.

Comment: what you say is when I have table name, but here I don't have anything except ResultsSet

Comment: then you would probably parse the resultset with a while and find the maximum size for each column

Comment: if i find i better way i will let you know

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was going to ask you the same.

Comment: @MajidNK are you going to do this treatement in so many places in your application because if so you might want to consider create a Utility class that will return int[] and takes as argument a resultset ican help you with that if you want

Comment: @achapahe Thank you for trying to help. Yes, my application is in fact a layered application in which I want my user to run any query he/she want but not to get this info directly from mysql but through my java program only. So I need this maximum length just because I want to produce him/her a formated decent output in the console(command line). So they answer is yes as he/she may do many queries in one/more tables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104111/discussion-between-achabahe-and-majid-nk).

Comment: hi i will make i new answer for your question

Answer (score 0):

You can cascade it with GREATEST like this:

```
SELECT 
  GREATEST(
    MAX(LENGTH(field_to_query1)), GREATEST( MAX(LENGTH(field_to_query2)), MAX(LENGTH(field_to_query3)) ))
FROM table_to_query;
```

Comment: Thank you, but as I mentioned already I do not have the table name, I have just ResultSet